# How to optimize elastic search query

Tags: php, elasticsearch

I have been reading through elastic search docs over the last few months and have continued to optimize my query, but I can't seem to get a search query below 500-600ms. Locally with less data I can get responses in ~80-200ms.

To outline what I am trying to accomplish:

I have 12 different models in Laravel that are searchable from a single search bar. As someone types it is searched and returned in a list of results.

Currently, I have this for my search query. Are there any references for how I can improve this? I looked into multi_match, but I was having issues with partial matches and specifying all fields.

```
$results = $this->elastic->search([
            'index' => config('scout.elasticsearch.index'),
            'type'  => $type ?? implode(',', array_keys($this->permissions, true, true)),
        'body'  => [
            'query' => [
                'bool' => [
                    'must'   => [
                        [
                            'query_string' => [
                                'query' => "$searchQuery*",
                            ],
                        ],
                    ],
                    'filter' => [
                        [
                            'term' => [
                                'account_id' => $accountId,
                            ],
                        ],
                    ],
                    'should' => [
                        [
                            'term' => [
                                '_type' => [
                                    'value' => 'customers',
                                    'boost' => 1.3,
                                ],
                            ],
                        ],
                        [
                            'term' => [
                                '_type' => [
                                    'value' => 'contacts',
                                    'boost' => 1.3,
                                ],
                            ],
                        ],
                        [
                            'term' => [
                                '_type' => [
                                    'value' => 'users',
                                    'boost' => 1.3,
                                ],
                            ],
                        ],
                        [
                            'term' => [
                                '_type' => [
                                    'value' => 'chart_accounts',
                                    'boost' => 1.2,
                                ],
                            ],
                        ],
                    ],
                ],
            ],
            'from'  => $from,
            'size'  => $size,
        ],
    ]);
```

Comment: If you are trying to implement type ahead, look at https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-suggesters-completion.html

Comment: That looks like exactly what I need, thanks! I'm going to see if I can get that implemented tomorrow